# How can I extract all links by searching on " yr of registration" of all pages using BeautifulSoup Python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape all links containing text as "view" by searching on "yr of registration" as "2015" and also not getting how to go on next page and up to last page to extract all links.

I have tried using anchor tag & its ID and using yr of reg & submit to extract all links, but not getting the wanted result.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://old.mciindia.org/InformationDesk/IndianMedicalRegister.aspx'

data = {
    'dnn$ctr588$IMRIndex$Txt_Year': 2015,
    'dnn$ctr588$IMRIndex$Submit_Btn': "Submit",
    }

r = requests.post(url, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for links in soup.find_all('a', id_='lnkDesc'):
    print(links['href'])
```

I want all links of yr of reg. of 2015 of text "view" up to last page.
How can I crack this?

Comment: I think you need to mimic the entire form submission including boundaries etc...

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Something here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+requests+multi-part+form

Comment: didnt find anything useful, any other way.